# R: match rows of a matrices and get location specific info

Tags: r, matrix

Say you have a matrix M1 as such:

```
    A B C D E F G H I J
353 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
288 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
275 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
236 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
235 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
227 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

the rownames are the values (they are not random they have meaning and it is what I want as I will explain).

Say you have another matrix M2 as such:

```
     A B C D E F G H I J AA
[1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[2,] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[3,] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[4,] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[5,] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[6,] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Note A to J is the same number of cols, except the 2 new cols, AA

Now, I want something like:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(M2)){
  if(M2[i,"AA"]==1){
    #-1 since I M1 doesnt have the AA column
    vec = M2[i,1:(ncol(M2)-1)]

    #BELOW is what I am not sure of what how to implement
    #get the rowname from M1 that matches vec, and replace M2[i,"AA"] = that value


  } 
}
```

The result should be 0, since in this example there are no rows of M1 matching any rows of M2[,A:J]

Comment: of course I misunderstood the question because there is no question. You want something like `...`, but this isn't the code you want? Does it give you the desired results? If it doesn't you didn't say why or what is wrong about the output. Which is critical. Even if it does something, your example doesn't make sense. that pattern does not show up in any row 3s in either matrix. And if it does, you want your code to return "elephant?" Where did that come from? You also refer to column BB, but that is no where to be found. I feel like I'm being punk'd

Comment: No problem, you are not being punked. the # is what I want to implement and wrote in as english not R. also for loops are bad in R so change suggestions on that would also be great.

Comment: loops aren't inherently bad, people just use them wrong